# How to enable SSH on elementary os

Tags: ssh

This isn't a question but instead a tutorial to install the SSH feature on elementary os. When I looked at forms it told me just to do

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

but then I got an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so what you actually have to do is enter these 2 commands in order

```
sudo apt-get install ssh-import-id
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

then restart your machine

Comment: Answering your own question is always appreciated at any SE site but please add the answer part separately as answer from answer field.

Answer (score 0):

no need for OpenSSH-server - ssh-import-id pulls it as a dependency.

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS Stack Exchange. Your contributions are appreciated. Please allow me to inform you that we like descriptive answers which doesn't require further clarification, also easy to understand for someone else with same problem and less technical knowledge. Have a nice day.